# Try, exception, question about a line of code

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

I want to know, what exactly does this line of code do?
Because I didn't find information about it, I know what is try except block.

raise Exception()

It's into a try except block:

```
try:

    raise Exception()

except:

    print('...')
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It will cause the code in the "except" block to get executed. As there is no specific exception listed after "except", then the except block will catch all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try-catch blocks operate by catching raised exceptions.

Try attempts to run a block of code. If the affirmationed block raises and exception, it signals for the catch block to execute.

Most languages also have a finally block (Try-Catch-Finally), which executes regardless of which block completes.

In the provided code, you have given an example of code which acts as a try block that fails to execute and raises an exception. This simulation shows that an exception raised calls the catch block.

Since your catch block is not defined to catch a specific exception raised, all exceptions raise the block's execution..